# Split Comma seperated values into multiple columns and an empty column next to it to map the name- Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a columns with numbers separated by comma now the values should be split into new columns.

```
 Site       UserId
   ABC           '456,567,67,96'
   DEF           '67,987'
```

The new Dataframe should look like:

```
Site     UserID              UserId1  UserId2  UserId3  UserId4
ABC     '456,567,67,96'      456       567      67        96
DEF     '67,987'             67        987
POC     '4321,96,912         4321      87       912
```

Also an empty column next to each column to map the numbers with the name.
user

```
 UserId UserName         Phone No 
  4321   EB_Meter         9980688666
    987    EB_Meter987    9255488721 
    912    DG_Meter912    8897634219
    567    Ups_Meter567   7263193155 
    456    Ups_Meter456   8987222112 
    96     DG_Meter96     
    67     DGB_Meter
```

So the final DataFrame is:

```
  Values              Value1  Name1            Phone1         Value2   Name2         Value3 Name3      Value4 Name4
 '456,567,67,96'       456    Ups_Meter456       8987222112    567      Ups_Meter567      67     DGB_Meter   96   DG_Meter96
    '67,987'            67    DGB_Meter                        987      EB_Meter987
    '4321,96,912        4321    EB_Meter          9980688666    96       DG_Meter96    912    DG_Meter912
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for new `DataFrame`:

```
df = df1['UserID'].str.strip("'").str.split(',',expand=True)
print (df)
      0    1     2     3
0   456  567    67    96
1    67  987  None  None
2  4321   96   912  None
```

Then convert `df2['UserId']` for strings for mapping data reshaped by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then reshape back to `DataFrame` by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df2['UserId'] = df2['UserId'].astype(str)
s = df2.set_index('UserId')['UserName']
df3 = df.stack(dropna=False).map(s).unstack()
print (df3)
              0             1            2           3
0  Ups_Meter456  Ups_Meter567    DGB_Meter  DG_Meter96
1     DGB_Meter   EB_Meter987          NaN         NaN
2      EB_Meter    DG_Meter96  DG_Meter912         NaN
```

Join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with change order of columns in `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), last flatten `MultiIndex` in list comprehension with `f-string`s and add column `df1[['UserID']]` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1, keys=('Value','Name'))
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,0], ascending=[True, False]))
df.columns = [f'{x}{y+1}' for x, y in df.columns]
df = df1.join(df)
print (df)
          UserID Value1         Name1 Value2         Name2 Value3  \
0  456,567,67,96    456  Ups_Meter456    567  Ups_Meter567     67   
1         67,987     67     DGB_Meter    987   EB_Meter987   None   
2    4321,96,912   4321      EB_Meter     96    DG_Meter96    912   

         Name3 Value4       Name4  
0    DGB_Meter     96  DG_Meter96  
1          NaN   None         NaN  
2  DG_Meter912   None         NaN
```

If necessary replace `None/NaN`s to empty strings by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.fillna('')
print (df)

          UserID Value1         Name1 Value2         Name2 Value3  \
0  456,567,67,96    456  Ups_Meter456    567  Ups_Meter567     67   
1         67,987     67     DGB_Meter    987   EB_Meter987          
2    4321,96,912   4321      EB_Meter     96    DG_Meter96    912   

         Name3 Value4       Name4  
0    DGB_Meter     96  DG_Meter96  
1                                  
2  DG_Meter912
```

Comment: The solution works fine however there a number of columns(Site,etc.) in the raw file along with the UserId..So the final dataframe should include those columns as well..

Comment: @Harishreddy - Change `df = df1[['UserID']].join(df)` to `df = df1.join(df)`

Comment: Hi @jezrael i want to add phone number column also..But the code is returning an error  df3=df.stack(dropna=False).map(s).unstack()..There are no duplicate Phone Number but it is returning the error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: @Harishreddy - Can you post new question?