# Merge and create multiple columns based in the number of columns present in the dataframe- Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, automation

I have a columns with numbers separated by comma now the values should be split into new columns.

```
 Site       UserId
   ABC           '456,567,67,96'
   DEF           '67,987'
```

The new Dataframe should look like:

```
Site     UserID              UserId1  UserId2  UserId3  UserId4
ABC     '456,567,67,96'      456       567      67        96
DEF     '67,987'             67        987
POC     '4321,96,912         4321      87       912
```

Also an empty column next to each column to map the numbers with the name and Phone Number.
user

```
 UserId UserName         PhoneNo 
  4321   EB_Meter         9980688666
    987    EB_Meter987    9255488721 
    912    DG_Meter912    8897634219
    567    Ups_Meter567   7263193155 
    456    Ups_Meter456   8987222112 
    96     DG_Meter96     
    67     DGB_Meter
```

So the final DataFrame is:

```
  Values              Value1  Name1            Phone1         Value2   Name2        Phone2       Value3  Name3        Phone3    Value4 Name4  Phone 4
 '456,567,67,96'      456     Ups_Meter456    8987222112      567      Ups_Meter567  7263193155     67      DGB_Meter               96   DG_Meter96
 '67,987'             67      DGB_Meter                        987      EB_Meter987   9255488721
 '4321,96,912         4321    EB_Meter          9980688666    96       DG_Meter96                  912    DG_Meter912  8897634219
```

Comment: How is this question different from [`this one`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585856/split-comma-seperated-values-into-multiple-columns-and-an-empty-column-next-to-i)?

Comment: You can try `.str.split(expand=True)` for the first problem and for the second one use `.map` for each column.

Comment: @MayankPorwal when i use "df.stack(dropna=False).map(s).unstack()" i get the following error- "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" although there is no duplicate phone no..

Comment: Is order of columns important in output?

Comment: @jezrael i dont think the order of columns is of much importance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are added multiple columns per `UserId`, so instead `map` is used [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with left join in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), reshaping is created by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df2['UserId'] = df2['UserId'].astype(str)
df3 = df1['UserId'].str.strip("'").str.split(',',expand=True)

df3 = (df3.reset_index()
          .melt('index', value_name='UserId')
          .merge(df2, on='UserId', how='left')
          .pivot(index='index', columns='variable')
          .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
          )
df3.columns = df3.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1] + 1}')

df = df1.join(df3)
print (df)
  Site         UserId UserId_1    UserName_1   PhoneNo_1 UserId_2  \
0  ABC  456,567,67,96      456  Ups_Meter456  8987222112      567   
1  DEF         67,987       67     DGB_Meter         NaN      987   

     UserName_2   PhoneNo_2 UserId_3 UserName_3 PhoneNo_3 UserId_4  \
0  Ups_Meter567  7263193155       67  DGB_Meter       NaN       96   
1   EB_Meter987  9255488721     None        NaN       NaN     None   

   UserName_4 PhoneNo_4  
0  DG_Meter96       NaN  
1         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @Harishreddy - It means there are duplicated rows in dataframe, I guess in df2, for some use is multiple Phone number, it is expected?

Comment: the user id and  phone numbers are unique but the UserName is same in some cases

Comment: @Harishreddy - If duplicated `UserId` how all processing data? e.g. first `4321` is changed to `456`

Comment: the user id is extracted from the backend database soo duplicated userId does not exist..

Comment: @Harishreddy - If no dupe, still not working? What return `print (df2['UserId'].duplicated(keep=False).sum())` in input data?

Comment: the code works fine...Just the order of the columns is desirable to have id,Name and the phone no....Currently it is Phone no,user id and name

Comment: @Harishreddy - OK, give me some time, please.

Comment: @Harishreddy - change `.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)` to `.sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)`, asnwer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[[ 'UserId1', 'UserId2', 'UserId3', 'UserId4']] = df['UserId'].str.split(",", expand=True)
```